# Partition of set into subsets of size at most k

Tags: combinatorics

I have a set of $N$ elements, and I want to generate all partitions of the set into subsets of cardinality at most $k$. For example, if $N = 4$ and $k=3$, for the set $S = \{a, b, c, d\}$ we have the partitions $(a)(b)(c)(d)$, $(a b)(c)(d)$, $(a c)(b)(d)$, $(a d)(b)(c)$, $(b c)(a)(d)$, $(b d)(a)(c)$, $(c d)(a)(b)$, $(a b)(c d)$, $(a c)(b d)$, $(a d)(b d)$. How many partitions are there for general $N$, $k$?

Comment: I see.  So am I right in saying you want the number of equivalence relations where no equivalence class has more than $k$ elements?

Comment: I think there is a typo in the question where $k=3$ in the example should read $k=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E_k(x)=\sum_{i=0}^k \frac{x^i}{i!}$ be the partial exponential series. Then the answer is
$$
N![x^N]\exp(E_k(x)-1)
$$
where $[x^N]f(x)$ is the coefficient of $x^N$ in the power series $f(x)$. This is the simplest expression I can think of for the solution.

For example, when $N=4$ and $k=2$, note
$$
\exp(x+\tfrac{x^2}2)=1+(x+\tfrac{x^2}2)+\tfrac12(x+\tfrac{x^2}2)^2+\tfrac16(x+\tfrac{x^2}2)^3+\tfrac1{24}(x+\tfrac{x^2}2)^4+\dots
$$
Extracting the coefficient of $x^4$, we get...

- a contribution of $\frac18$ from the $\tfrac12(x+\tfrac{x^2}2)^2$ term,
- a contribution of $\frac14$ from the $\tfrac16(x+\tfrac{x^2}2)^3$ term, and
- a contribution of $\frac1{24}$ from the $\tfrac1{24}(x+\tfrac{x^2}2)^4$ term.

There are no contributions from anything else. Adding these up and multiplying by $N!=24$, we get $3+6+1=10$.

Comment: Also, when $k=\infty$, the result is $N![x^N]\exp(\exp(x)-1)$, which agrees with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number#Generating_function

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive formula.  If $T(N,k)$ is the number of partitions of $\{1,\dots,N\}$ into parts of cardinality not exceeding $k$ then 
$$T(N+1,k)=\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}{N\choose k}T(N-n,k)$$ because for $n=0,\dots,k-1$ we choose the $n$ elements in the same partition as $1$ and then partition the remaining $N-n$ elements.

The initial condition is $T(0,k)= 1$ and we can define $T(n,k)$ arbitrarily for $n<0.$

This python script

```
from math import factorial
from collections import defaultdict

def binomial(n,k):
    if k > n or n < 0:
        return 0
    return factorial(n)//(factorial(k)*factorial(n-k))

N = 10
k = 2
T = defaultdict(int)
T[0,k] = 1

for m in range(1,N+1):
    T[m,k] = sum(binomial(m-1, n)*T[m-1-n, k] for n in range(k))

for n in range(N+1):
    print(n, T[n, k])
```

produces the output

```
0 1
1 1
2 2
3 4
4 10
5 26
6 76
7 232
8 764
9 2620
10 9496
```

which turns out to be [OEIS A000085](http://oeis.org/A000085)